# How can you perform this improper integral as Mathematica does?

Tags: python, r, math, julia, numerical-integration

Take this Mathematica code:

```js
f[x_] := Exp[-x];
c = 0.9;
g[x_] := c*x^(c - 1)*Exp[-x^c];
SetPrecision[Integrate[f[x]*Log[f[x]/g[x]], {x, 0.001, \[Infinity]}],20]
```

Mathematica computes this without problem and gives the answer `0.010089328699390866240`. I would like to be able to perform similar integrals but I don't have a copy of Mathematica. Just naively implementing it in scipy, for example, using a standard quadrature library fails sadly because f(x) and g(x) get arbitrarily close to 0. Here is an example in Python using standard quadrature which fails due to the infinite precision needed.:

```py
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return sum([ps[idx]*lambdas[idx]*np.exp(- lambdas[idx] * x) for idx in range(len(ps))])

def g(x):
    return scipy.stats.weibull_min.pdf(x, c=c)

c = 0.9
ps = [1]
lambdas = [1]
eps = 0.001  # weibull_min is only defined for x > 0
print(quad(lambda x: f(x) * np.log(f(x) / g(x)), eps, np.inf)) # Output
```

should be greater than 0

How, in code, can one perform this improper integral as Mathematica does? I don't mind which free language/library is used.

Comment: 1. lib + language-agnostic sounds like oxymoron ... any lib neads at least header file and that can not be language-agnostic ... you can have a lib for more languages but hardly for all of them...  2. recommending off-site stuff and or libs is off-topic here so +Close 3. you can implement this on your own just write a parser for the input file that converts it into expresion strings which you than integrate numerically using rectangular rule or whatever else ... algebraic integration is hard

Comment: @Spektre Thank you for the explanation. 1) I must have misunderstood the language-agnostic tag. I will delete it. 2) I am not asking for anything off-site. I would like code as an answer. 3) Sadly that doesn't work for reasons I tried to explain in the question. I will expand on them.

Comment: @Anush " I am not asking for anything off-site" ...you specifically asked us to recommend a library which would fulfil the requirement. That is inevitably going to be someone's opinion of what the best thing is. Which, in theory at least, gives people the opportunity to promote products / services / their own rubbish code - which is why it's off-topic. If you actually want a code example (which might of course use some library in the process) then I suggest you amend your wording before the question is closed by mods. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson Is it better now?

Comment: you should probably amend the title too

Comment: @Anush I retracted my close vote also SCIPY implies python so I added the tag. Google expression evaluation that is the core of arbitrary numeric integration. I do not code in python so I can not be of help but there must be some package in python for it. The integration it self is just a for cycle going through all points of integrated function adding the values together... however infinite range is doable only if the values are going to zero on the infinite end of range otherwise you need algebraic integration. Implementing that is hardcore math and not doable for arbitrary functions

Comment: other option is convert your function into taylor or other polynomial series and integrate than algebraicaly ... that is easy ... or use Laplacce/Zed transforms ... but all of that is more math than programming ...

Comment: @Spektre Thank you. I am *not* looking for a solution specifically in Python so is python really appropriate tag?

Comment: @Anush Well that depends ... what languages you know/accept .. for truly language agnostic answer the answer would need just pseudo code and that means specific algorithm so specific method and as you did not specify any boundaries to what kind of functions, domain, ranges, integrals and precision you want/need is this too broad to fit 30K limit and it would be also way too much work ... its usually better to chose language you are familiar with as a tag ... or at least add a list into question but still you need to specify more closely the math details ...

Comment: @Spektre I would accept code in any free language. I'll add a few language tags if that helps.

Comment: HINT: log[f(x)/g(x)] = log(f(x)) - log(g(x))

Comment: @HongOoi `quad(lambda x: f(x) * (np.log(f(x)) - np.log(g(x))), 0.0001, np.inf)` also fails for the same reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very interesting problem.

First note that the integrand

```
from numpy import exp

def f(x):
    return exp(-x) 

def g(x):
    c = 0.9
    return c * x**(c - 1) * exp(-x ** c)

def integrand(x):
    return f(x) * log(f(x) / g(x))
```

has a singularity at 0 that is *integrable*, and the integral over [0, infty] can be evaluated *analytically*. After some manipulation, you'll find

```
import numpy
import scipy.special

c = 0.9

# euler_mascheroni constant
gamma = 0.57721566490153286060
val = scipy.special.gamma(c + 1) - 1 - numpy.log(c) + (c - 1) * gamma

print(val)
```

```
0.0094047810750603
```

[wolfram-alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%28exp%28-x%29%20*%20log%28exp%28-x%29%20%2F%20%280.9%20*%20x%20**%20%28-0.1%29%20*%20exp%28-x**0.9%29%29%29%2C%200%2C%20infty%29) gives its value correctly to many digits. To reproduce this with numerical methods, a good first try is always [tanh-sinh quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanh-sinh_quadrature) (e.g., from [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy), a project of mine). Cut off the domain at some large value, where the function is almost 0 anyway, then:

```py
from numpy import exp, log
import quadpy


def f(x):
    return exp(-x)


def g(x):
    c = 0.9
    return c * x**(c - 1) * exp(-x ** c)


def integrand(x):
    return f(x) * log(f(x) / g(x))


val, err = quadpy.tanh_sinh(integrand, 0.0, 100.0, 1.0e-8)
print(val)
```

```
0.009404781075063085
```

---

Now for some other things that, perhaps surprisingly, do *not* work so well.

When seeing an integral of the type `exp(-x) * f(x)`, the first thing that should come to mind is [Gauss-Laguerre quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Laguerre_quadrature). For example with [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) (one of my projects):

```py
import numpy
import quadpy

c = 0.9


def f(x):
    return numpy.exp(-x)


def g(x):
    return c * x ** (c - 1) * numpy.exp(-x ** c)


scheme = quadpy.e1r.gauss_laguerre(100)
val = scheme.integrate(lambda x: numpy.log(f(x) / g(x)))

print(val[0])
```

This gives

```
0.010039543105755215
```

which is a surprisingly bad approximation for the actual value despite the fact that we were using 100 integration points. This is due to the fact that the integrand cannot be approximated very well by polynomials, especially the terms `log(x)` and `x ** c`:

```py
import numpy
from numpy import exp, log, ones
from scipy.special import gamma
import quadpy


c = 0.9


def integrand(x):
    return exp(-x) * (-x - log(c) - (c - 1) * log(x) - (-x ** c))


scheme = quadpy.e1r.gauss_laguerre(200)
val = scheme.integrate(lambda x: -x - log(c) - (c - 1) * log(x) - (-x ** c))[0]

vals = numpy.array([
    - scheme.integrate(lambda x: x)[0],
    -log(c) * scheme.integrate(lambda x: ones(x.shape))[0],
    -(c - 1) * scheme.integrate(lambda x: log(x))[0],
    scheme.integrate(lambda x: x ** c)[0]
])
euler_mascheroni = 0.57721566490153286060
exact = numpy.array([
    -1.0,
    -log(c),
    euler_mascheroni * (c-1),
    gamma(c + 1)
])
print("approximation, exact, diff:")
print(numpy.column_stack([vals, exact, abs(vals - exact)]))
print()
print("sum:")
print(sum(vals))
```

```
approximation, exact, diff:
[[-1.00000000e+00 -1.00000000e+00  8.88178420e-16]
 [ 1.05360516e-01  1.05360516e-01  6.93889390e-17]
 [-5.70908293e-02 -5.77215665e-02  6.30737142e-04]
 [ 9.61769857e-01  9.61765832e-01  4.02488825e-06]]

sum:
0.010039543105755278
```

Comment: Great to hear from the author of quadpy!

Comment: Thank you for this. It's not clear to me that the 100 cutoff in " quadpy.tanh_sinh(integrand, 0.0, 100.0, 1.0e-8)" is a generally safe thing to do. The function is the log of the ratio of very small numbers at this point. How do we know that this can be ignored?

Comment: It's the log of the ratio of small numbers, _times a negative exponential_, so there is reason to believe it's small. And it has to decay very fast, too, otherwise it wouldn't be integrable. Plot the function, check it's value: It's around 10^(-42).

Comment: Would you mind showing how you did the analytic integration?

Comment: It's super elementary: Just split out the log like `Log(x*y/z) = Log(x) + Log(y) - Log(z)`, and then look at the individual terms like `int(exp(-x) * x)` (which is 1), `int(exp(-x) * log(c))` (which is `log(c)`) etc.

Answer (score 5):

In `julia`, the `QuadGK` package can do these integrals. Just doing this directly you will bump into issues, as you note:

```
f(x) = exp(-x)
g(x; c=0.9) = c*x^(c - 1)*exp(-x^c)
h(x) = f(x) * log(f(x)/g(x))
using QuadGK
a,b = 0.001, Inf
quadgk(h, a, b)  # errors
```

But expanding the log(f/g) to log(f) - (log(c) + (c-1)log(x) + x^c) we can get each term to integrate:

```
c = 0.9
quadgk(x -> f(x) * -x, a,b)
quadgk(x -> -f(x)*log(c), a,b)
quadgk(x -> -f(x)*(c-1)*log(x), a,b)
quadgk(x -> f(x) * x^c, a,b)
```

Adding up the values gives the answer.

You can also get the answer by filtering out the NaN values, which may be much more inefficient:

```
h1(x) = isnan(h(x)) ? 0.0 : h(x)
quadgk(h1, a,b) # (0.010089328699390816, 9.110982026738999e-11)
```

Using `big(a)` and `big(b)` can get you more decimal points.

Comment: This looks great. Could you give the complete Julia code for newbies please.